# Showing $(x^\alpha)=\alpha x^{\alpha - 1} \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, given that we already showed it for $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: calculus

I know there are several other easier methods to do this, but here is the scenario:

- Using the inverse function theorem, we've showed that $(x^\alpha)=\alpha x^{\alpha - 1} \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$,
- Below is a claim on my notes:

> We proved the statement for rational exponent, and $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \exists \frac{p_n}{Q_n}\rightarrow\alpha$, so by the continuity of the exponential function the statement is proven.

I'm firstly asking an intuitive description on why is it true, then formally why is it true. I do not understand how continuity is used here.

What I've attempted so far:

- We have 2 functions (let's keep the domain $\mathbb{R}^+$ for now),
  $f(x) = x^\alpha$, and
  $g(x)=\alpha\left(x^{\frac1\alpha}\right)^{\alpha-1}$. The function
  $(gf)(x)$ is actually $f'(x)$, but let us forget this for now.
- $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and $g(x)$ is continuous on the image of $f(x)$
- Thus, $gf(x)$ is continuous on the image of $f(x)$, which is $\mathbb{R}^+$

If you are confused on what I'm trying to do, basically I'm trying to use the transference principle, $f$ continuous on $x_0 \iff \forall (x_n), x_n \to x_0, \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$. To do this, I firstly need a continuous function, then I need to a sequence to set up the usage of the transference principle.

But the issue I keep on running to is that I don't know the correct $(\text{function, sequence})$ to use. I keep on finding out that I let $\alpha$ to be constant. Maybe I need a function on the exponent instead (like a function $h(\alpha)=x^\alpha$, but I don't see how this helps)?

**Edit (Attempt 2), after Lulu's comments:**

Firstly, for a fixed $a \in \mathbb{R}$ let us define 2 functions:

1. $f(x)=x^a$, this function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, and is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$
2. $g(x)=ax^{a-1}$, this function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, and is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

We have shown (somehow) that $f'(x) = g(x), \forall a \in \mathbb{Q}$. We should note that for $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, $f'(x)$ is also a continuous function.

Now, let us define a sequence $(x_n):= x^{\frac{p_n}{q_n}}, (x_n) \to x^a, a \in \mathbb{R\setminus Q}$. Then let me *try* to use the transference principle:

$$
A = \lim_{n \to \infty} f'(x_n)= \lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n) \overset{\mbox{g cont}}{=} g(x^a)
$$

Using Lulu's comment, this way I can conclude that $ f'(x^a) = A$. But suppose I don't know that, then I'm not sure if the previous equality is true.

Comment: Two continuous functions that coincide on a dense set must coincide everywhere (exercise).  But...it is hard to say much about your question since you don't explain how you have defined $x^{\alpha}$.  Perhaps you have defined it as the continuous extension of the same function on the rationals or perhaps you defined it using logarithms (in which case you could simply use properties of $\ln (x)$.).

Comment: If what I'm trying to do is not understandable then I'm also happy to accept an answer that just that ignores what I tried to do.

Comment: It is perfectly understandable, save for the fact that you don't tell us how you have defined $x^{\alpha}$.

Comment: @lulu well, we don't. This was from my calc1 course back in the first semester, things were kept simple. Literally on the notes: 'Statement: $(x^\alpha)' = \alpha x^{\alpha-1}$'

Comment: If the function is undefined, you can't prove anything about it.  If, as seems likely, your source just instructs you to assume that the function, whatever it means, is continuous on all of $\mathbb R$ then you can can use the fact I mention (that continuous functions which coincide on a dense set must coincide everywhere.)

Comment: @lulu would my 2nd attempt work here?

Comment: It just not clear what you are assuming about the function. That makes it hard to know what sort of arguments are justified.  You assume continuity, but then start saying things about the derivative, though continuity does not imply that the derivative even exists.  To keep it simple:  just assume continuity.  Use the fact that we have two continuous functions that coincide on a dense set.  That's enough.